# Where to ask for username while creating profile?

Tags: username, flow

I am creating a mobile app where user can create profile with various fields and with my current approach I allow user to enter all the field details and when clicking on "Save" button, I ask for username.

- Is that correct place to ask for user name or I can optimize it?
- Where should be the ideal flow for user to ask for unique username?

Answer (score 1):

First consider if your application requires a username. Would an email address suffice?

Generally, the fewer form fields the better. For the initial registration, create the shortest possible form. Then, when the new user returns to the app, you can prompt her for a bit more information. This sort of "progressive profiling" saves user time and usually leads to a greater number of registrations.

Luke Wroblewski's *Web Form Designs* is already 10 years old, but it's still the best source of guidelines for building web forms. See https://static.lukew.com/webforms_lukew.pdf for some of the logic and testing behind these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to add username field also inside details only as it is in your current approach. Because asking username after clicking save button is increasing number of clicks and creating new flow for username only.

Comment: Yes thats what i was thinking.. However i dont wanna mix profile details with username.. as it is different kind of profile